# Is this a weed growing in pot?

Tags: identification, containers, weeds, wildflowers

My concrete rooftop is so hot, that cactuses and weeds are pretty much the only thing that survive. We’re in the Caribbean.

So I was surprised when I saw something that doesn’t look like a cactus growing in one of the pots. They don’t look like the usual weeds, and it has big leaves with only one root. It even has flowers.

Are these weeds? If they are, would it make sense to keep them in the pot?

[image]
[image][image][image]

Comment: Weeds can have flowers, too. Just usually not pretty ones. After the flowers, there will be seeds. Usually a lot of seeds. Probably best to get rid of it now, before you have weed seeds all over the place.

Comment: How do you know it’s a weed?

Comment: Isn't that some mint species!

Comment: I don't know if it's a weed. Plants that volunteer are usually weeds, so it's not a good idea to let an unidentified volunteer go to seed. By all means keep trying to identify it, and if you can figure out what it is before it goes to seed, let that guide your decisions. But if it goes to seed before you can figure it out, it's better to get rid of it before the seeds fully mature.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is *Laportea aestuans*, the West Indian woodnettle.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laportea_aestuans

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's a Bernardia Dodecandra. What is a weed to you? You could call it a happy accident and enjoy it's lovely tiny flowers. They'd certainly fit in with your desert themed plants.